# Materialize dropdown not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, materialize, conditional-operator

I've made a navbar with a dropdown that displays the user's options when the user is logged in, if is not logged in, the navbar will show a Log In and Sign Up buttons instead of the dropdown. When the user is logged in, the dropdown is being shown but is not working. This is the render method:

```
var navDropdownBtn = this.props.loggedIn ? (
        <div>
            <li>
                <a className="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">
                    <i className="material-icons left">account_circle</i>
                    {this.props.currentUsername}
                    <i className="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </div>
    ) : (
            <div>
                <li><NavLink to="/login">Log In</NavLink ></li >
                <li><NavLink to="/signup">Sign Up</NavLink></li>
            </div>
        )



    var sidenavBtns = this.props.loggedIn ? (
        <div>                
            <li className="sidenav-close">
                <NavLink to={"/profile/" + this.props.currentUsername + "/"}>
                    <i className="material-icons left">account_circle</i>
                    {this.props.currentUsername}
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="divider"></li>
            <li className="sidenav-close"><NavLink to="/" onClick={this.props.appHandleLogOut}>Log Out</NavLink></li>

        </div>
    ) : (
            <div>
                <li className="sidenav-close"><NavLink to="/login">Log In</NavLink ></li >
                <li className="sidenav-close"><NavLink to="/signup">Sign Up</NavLink></li>
            </div>
        )




    return (
        <div>
            <div className="navbar-fixed">
                <ul id="dropdown1" className="dropdown-content">
                    <li><NavLink to={"/profile/" + this.props.currentUsername + "/"}>My Profile</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="/" onClick={this.props.appHandleLogOut}>Log Out</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
                <nav>
                    <div className="nav-wrapper indigo">
                        <div className="container">
                            <ul className="left">
                                <NavLink to="/" className="brand-logo" >LOGO</NavLink>
                            </ul>
                            <a className="sidenav-trigger hide-on-larg" data-target="idSidenav">
                                <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
                            </a>
                            <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                                {navDropdownBtn}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <ul className="sidenav" id="idSidenav">
                {sidenavBtns}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
```

Then if I force the ternary to true like this

```
var navDropdownBtn = true ? (
        <div>...
```

the dropdown works fine, but ofc is not a solution. what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried logging the status of your conditionals right before the ternary to see what values you're getting?

Comment: Where and when do you initialise the dropdown? Initialisation must run after it has been added to the dom.

Comment: @JoelHager yes, I just did it and it's always true, anyways if it wasn't true, the Log In and Sing Up buttons would show up instead of the dropdown.

Comment: @SeanDoherty I did intialize it inside componentDidMount with M.AutoInit().

Comment: So the init comes after the conditional is run? If the init runs before the element is in the dom it will not work. Did you try initialising directly on the component, rather than the blanket autoinit?

Comment: Yes I also tried intializing directly, but nothing  had changed. Turns out that the init was running before the conditional like you said, tho the init was inside the componentDidMount method. I solved it initializing it inside componentDidUpdate method, so thanks!